# Interaction between multiple files

Tags: c++, c, preprocessor

I need to have two files in my setup. The second file will perform some variable definitions, but based on preprocessor directives read on the first file. The first file will then have to do stuff like set up an object, using the variables defined in the second file as parameters to the constructor.

Is this possible to have this back and forth information between two source files?

To sum up (something like this):

*`File1` uses a `#define status true`.

*`File2` sees the preprocessor directive of `File1`.
If its `true` it sets up some variables.

*`File1` then initializes an object with the variables from `File2`.
In this example, steps 1 and 3 are redundant. Because if `File1` sets up the preprocessor directive, it can know the variables that `File2` which is going to set up - by hardcoding means.

But I just want to experiment with what information I can pass back and forth... Can `File2` read preprocessor directives from `File1`? Can then `File1` read back information from `File2`?

EDIT (pseudocode):

```
//file1.cpp
#define status true

//this class is defined previously
//var1 was defined in file2.cpp
MyObject object1(var1);



//file2.cpp
//status is the preprocessor directive from file1
if (status == true)
{
  int var1 = 1;
}
```

Comment: Preprocessor directives are strictly per-file, if you remember that #include is the same as copy/paste. It is normal to set a directive in a header file and include it in multiple other files but there is no communication between files.

Comment: You write *"file, file"* but do you mean a header file? or a .cpp file? Are you aware of concept of translation units?

Comment: If you want one file to see the preprocessor directives in another file then you are going to have to `#include` the second file in the first. And therefore the second file should be a header file, with all that implies. But putting preprocessor directives in a header file to guide the compilation of your code is a common enough thing to do.

Comment: @user7860670 The files are either `.cpp` or `.h`. No, I am not aware of the concept of translation units.

Comment: @john Therefore, if I include the second file in the first, and then the first in the second, then each file will be able to see everything in the other file?

Comment: Then you should read some books explaining basics of c++ build process, especially parts focusing on preprocessor and translation units. Also implementing a c99 preprocessor is a good exercise.

Comment: @user1584421 No, mutual inclusion leads to an infinite regress. If you want two files to see everything in each file, then put them into a single file. The compiler reads your code from top to bottom, there's nothing you can do about that. It sounds like you want the compiler to see everything at once.

Comment: @user1584421 An actual example of what you want (instead of a description) would make this much more concrete. I'm sure you're not trying to do anything strange, but probably going the wrong way about it.

Comment: @john I added pseudocode in the question.

Comment: @user1584421 That seems impossible. You are expecting a globally declared variable `object1` to be initialised depending on code executed after that initialisation occurs. The obvious thing to do would be to move the `status` logic into the constructor for `MyObject` is there any reason you cannot do that?

Comment: @john I was asked to move all the var definitions (or pin definitions for an embedded platform) in an exteral file...

Comment: If you were asked to do something, then whoever asked you to do it should be able to tell you how they expect you to do it.

Comment: @user1584421 Tricky, hard to know what to advise without understanding more about the situation. Like molbdnilo says I would go back to the person who asked you to do this. It might be that they don't appreciate the issues, or it might be that you misunderstood in some way.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no interaction between preprocessor directives in multiple files.

If you recall, `#include` is just automated copy/paste. So you can put your directive in a header file, then `#include` that file into your other files. When you update the directive in the header file it will be like you updated the directive in both files, so they can't get out of sync, but there is still no cross-file interaction.

Officially, a *translation unit* is a source file after processing all the `#include`s. Preprocessor directives in one translation unit can't affect any other translation unit.

Comment: What if I want to have a file that will be used as configuration? Can I have that file define preprocessor directives? And can another header file read those directives from the configuration file?

Comment: @user1584421 then you can include that file into the other files where you want the preprocessor to know the configuration

Comment: But can I have the parameters as preprocessor directives? Would something like `#define DEBUG true` work? Or the preprocessor directives cannot be read by other files? Should the configuration parameters be variables instead?

Comment: @user1584421 everything that you #include behaves as if it's the same file. #include is copy-paste.